# filename not showing, but img gets uploaded?

Tags: php

```
$path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/img/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
if($ufile !=none)
{
   if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'], $path))
   {
       echo "Successful<BR/>";

       echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name']."<BR/>";
       echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size']."<BR/>";
       echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type']."<BR/>";
       echo "<img src=\"$path\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\">";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "Error";
   }
}

die();
```

Why does

```
echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name']."<BR/>";
```

Not give me the filename? the other information does not get echoed either

I am very sorry if this is a dumb question, does it have something to do with form method being POST ?

Comment: You should be using `$_FILES` instead of `$HTTP_POST_FILES` as those are deprecated.

Comment: and your index is wrong, it's not `ufile`

Comment: and you should `move_uploaded_file` to move your file instead of copying it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 3):

You've simply assumed the upload succeeded. `$HTTP_POST_FILES` (or the `$_FILES` you *should* be using) can still be populated with data if the upload fails. You **MUST** check the `['error']` parameter before doing ANYTHING with the upload, e.g.

```
if ($_FILES['ufile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['ufile']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

As well, your code is insecure, allowing a malicious user to scribble a file ANYWHERE on your server they want. Do not use `copy()` on uploaded files either. `move_uploaded_file()` exists for a reason. use it.

Comment: This option will be avalible to a selected few, admins, i do check if session is set, i doubt it will be abused, and i will have the IP if it does, so ..

Comment: But yes, i will take your advice in to acount and fix it now

Comment: @john: who's to say the admins can't trash the system? since this code allows them to scribble anywhere on the server, they can trivially upload a script to the document root and `exec('rm -rf /')` within it. boom goes your server along with the logs to show who did it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [move-uploaded-file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move uploaded file.

HTTP_POST_FILES are deprecated, use $_FILES.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php This should help you.